# failure when using self-build opencv

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I make a small change to opencv's source file (i'm sure the change is right) and rebuid it with cmake and make. Then i copy the corresponding lib files to replace their counterparts under /ros/fuerte/lib. When i run my program which needs opencv there are weired runtime problems (program just die and exit suddenly) although they compile successfully. And the problem just come up randomly. e.g., when processing images, it run well for some images while fail for the other. when i use the shipped opencv's lib it's always fine so i'm sure it's not a problem of my codes. What i should pay attention to when building opencv by myself? I know that on windows we should distinguish the debug version from the release version. So which version does Fuerte's shipped opencv use? debug, release, or release with debug info?

besides, i also use this method to change the version of opencv used with ROS. i.e., replace opencv's include and lib files under ros/fuerte/include and ros/fuerte/lib respectively. There are also weird runtime errors  as above.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60453/failure-when-using-self-build-opencv/) by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 741 on 2013-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to configure with the correct install paths and install. But you should not do that into /opt/ros as it will break anything else using those libraries unless you're very careful.

Anything that depends on your changed opencv should be rebuilt from source as well.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0